# Autocorrelation to measure lag effect

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, lags

Is there something similar to **Autocorrelation** but instead of measuring *"correlation of a signal with a delayed copy of itself"*, measuring correlation of a signal with a delayed copy of another value?

My use case is identifying the lag from advertising spend and conversions. For example if I spend $10 in TV I will see the full effect *n* days later.

Comment: Search for *cross-correlation*.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!